# getting a backlit keyboard to work with an older motherboard

Tags: usb, keyboard

So, I have this keyboard: https://perixx.com/lt_furniture_3/perixx-periboard-317-backlit-keyboard.html

And this motherboard:  https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/50378/intel-desktop-board-dg33tl.html

The keyboard is supposed to be USB 2.0 compatible, and the motherboard has all USB 2.0 ports.  I have updated to the most recent BIOS I can find.

The keyboard works fine in other computers from the era.  And I have a non-backlit keyboard that works fine with the above motherboard.  So it seems to definitely be a compatibility issue of some kind, not a hardware failure.  (Or at least I hope not!)

I'm willing to purchase a USB expansion card if necessary, but I'm worried it won't matter since the board is already USB 2.0 compatible.  Has anyone ever run into a problem like this?

Suggestions are much welcomed.  Thank you!

Comment: Is it just the backlight that is not working or the whole keyboard?

Comment: @DavidPostill Actually the backlight works fine.  The keyboard even works in Windows 10 after it boots.  But I need to be able to do stuff like hit F2 to get into the BIOS, and choose which boot device to use from grub2.  None of that works.

Comment: Did you enable "Legacy USB Support" in the BIOS settings?

Comment: @Saurabh So please [edit] the question with the updated information.